# Trapped Surfaces. Any good articles?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations, event-horizon

I'm currently writing a dissertation on [trapped surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapped_null_surface) as [minimal surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surfaces). I have exhausted all of the resources I have, and the internet is pretty limited (in that it is fairly repetitive on just defining what a trapped surface is).

I wondered if anyone could recommend any articles/papers which delve into the more mathematical side or even more detail on these surfaces (in particular as the [apparent horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_horizon)).

Comment: What have you looked at so far?  Have you seen all of hte Ashtekar and Krishnan papers?  The sean hayward stuff?  My dissertation?

Comment: So far I've used several books, namely on Spacetime, Geometry, Cosmology, the Conformal structure of spacetime and black holes.

Comment: Sorry, no I'm not familiar with those papers?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0934

The bibliography has a bunch of citations to related papers.  The Ashtekar and Krishnan series is very, very good, there are a bunch of them in the arxiv, and here is the one on living reviews in relativity:

http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2004-10/

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it, I look forward to going through them.